# what is the difference between getBuffer() and CreateRenderTargetView in directx 11?

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, rendertarget

I am new to DirectX11 and learning it. (I come from openGL background).

I am confused and trying to understand what exactly does the following API calls do and what is the difference between them:

```
ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), ( LPVOID* )&pBackBuffer );
```

and

```
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView( pBackBuffer, NULL, &g_pRenderTargetView );
pBackBuffer->Release();
```

What does `GetBuffer` really do ? How are we then using the `pBackBuffer` in `CreateRenderTargetView` ? Also, can someone explain or point me to a link that explains, what is a **render target view** ? The [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) didn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i recall, the     `GetBuffer()` returns the pointer to the internal backbuffer that devices use.
your then from there create a `RenderTarget` that you can bind as your `"Real backbuffer"` target.

think of it as :
    `pBackbuffer = glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);`

thats how i remember it. ( was some time ago i did this with dx11 )

edit*
And a `rendertargetview`, is a `framebuffer`. it´s a texture that you can bind to be read and writen to.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, `getBuffer` returns the pointer to actual buffer. `CreateRenderTargetView` makes this buffer a render target (aka Framebuffer) which is then bound to in the rendering pipeline. PS: RenderTargetView doesn't create another buffer.

Comment: Yes, instead of returning a int (like opengl dose) you have to create a interface from it. they just like to call it with fancy names!

Comment: ha ha, yeah I couldn't agree more!

Comment: Please note that you can't read from RenderTargetView, for that you need to create a ShaderResourceView. @Tordin we all like fancy names ))